# Converting xml data using Python

Tags: python, xml, string

I have a large xml data. The format is given as following:

```
  <person>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <address> London, xxx street, xxx building</address>
  </person>
  <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <address> Canberra, xxx street, xxx building, xxx floor, xxx room,
                 xxx  bed</address>
  </person>
```

## be careful about the address!

I want to get the following result:

```
  Tom^18^London, xxx street, xxx building
  John^22^Canberra, xxx street, xxx building, xxx floor, xxx room,xxx  bed
```

The data is fairly large, and I hope I can read line by line thus there will not be the problem of memory. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why it looks in this way, however, I get the data in this format.

Comment: That's not XML. You need to tell whoever is sending you this kind of data to fix his "xml" generation code so it actually produces XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the input is a well-formed xml.

To process a large xml file with limited memory you could use [`ElementTree.iterparse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

def getelements(source, tag):
    context = iter(etree.iterparse(source, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context) # get root element
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == tag:
            yield elem
            root.clear() # free memory

for elem in getelements('big.xml', 'person'):
    print '^'.join(elem.find(tag).text for tag in 'name age address'.split())
```

You could add a special processing for a multiline text inside a tag (as in your example for `address`) e.g., you could use `re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)` to normalize whitespace.

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/h4B6X)

```
Tom^18^London, xxx street, xxx building
John^22^Canberra, xxx street, xxx building, xxx floor, xxx room, xxx bed
```

If input xml might contain `'^'` and you'd like to escape it then you could use [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv#csv.writer) to produce output.

Answer (score 6):

Don't torture yourself by parsing strings if there is an xml library available -- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for example. If you want to stick with python's *batteries included* then have a look at [dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Comment: Thanks. I want to know whether I could you the lxml, since the data is very large. Using python to read line by line, it's possible to do it.

Comment: @FrankWANG - For streaming XML, take a look at sax (http://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax)

Comment: @FrankWANG - you certainly can use lxml to process large data sets - I have just used lxml to process over a million XML documents located in around 480 files (a total of about 5GB of data), and the iterparse() function made it possible to keep memory usage very slim. It stayed at around 70MB, even with the rest of my framework loaded.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your xml is not valid:

- `\`(backslash) in xml tags
- `<person>` tags are not closed

After fix the problems above.
Your problem can be solved by `xpath` which is provided by `lxml` module.
BTW, there is a command line tool called `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//person' -v 'normalize-space(concat(name, "^", age, "^", address))' -n input.xml
Tom^18^ London, xxx street, xxx building
John^22^ Canberra, xxx street, xxx building, xxx floor, xxx room, xxx bed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Beutiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html), I use it always for xml and html (although it is a bit slow)